# How do I loop through items in XML in Nokogiri in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Given I have XML [from this address](http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=PbFVZfjTXJQWrnJp&location=London&date=Today), how would I loop through the `search/events/event` events? What I mean is loop through the `event` items and print their details to the screen? So far I have the following code:

```
get_xml('/events/search', :location => 'London, United Kingdom', :date => 'Today').at('events')
```

`get_xml` being the method which takes the XML from the link above and selects the `events` node. How would I loop though the items in that `events` node?

Comment: Instead of "from this address", give us a sample of the xml. That ensures that the answer is still relevant next week when the url does down.

Comment: I agree with @pguardiario . Links break all the time, but Stack overflow is forever. Please include a brief, edited example of the xml that you expect to receive. his will help any future people experiencing similar issues to also find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'rexml/document'

# Web search for
url = 'http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=PbFVZfjTXJQWrnJp&location=London&date=Today'

# get the XML data as a string
xml_data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body

# extract event information
doc = REXML::Document.new(xml_data)
doc.elements.each('search/events/event/title') do |ele|
   titles = ele.text
   p titles
end
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\vinothini\Desktop>ruby sample_nokogiri.rb
"The Ladykillers"
"The 39 Steps"
"Wotever Sex 6 August"
"Phoenix Fringe"
"The Lion King"
"One Man, Two Guvnors"
"Tutorfair event 6th Aug"
"Thriller - Live"
"The Color Purple"
"Summer School Mid-Term Party"
```

Am i understood your requirement correctly?

Comment: -1 for not using nokogiri