# How would I construct a Hash from this scenario in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, hash, rexml

Given I have the following code:

```
  ENDPOINT = 'http://api.eventful.com'
  API_KEY  = 'PbFVZfjTXJQWrnJp'

  def get_xml(url, options={})
    compiled_url = "#{ENDPOINT}/rest#{url}" << "?app_key=#{API_KEY}&sort_order=popularity"
    options.each { |k, v| compiled_url << "&#{k.to_s}=#{v.to_s}" }
    REXML::Document.new((Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(URI.escape(compiled_url)))))
  end

  def event_search(location, date)
    get_xml('/events/search', 
      :location => "#{location}, United Kingdom",
      :date     => date
    )
  end
```

And we access the XML data formatted by `REXML::Document` like this:

```
events = event_search('London', 'Today').elements
```

And we can access these elements like this (this prints all the titles in the events):

```
events.each('search/events/event/title') do |title|
  puts title.text
end
```

The XML I'm using can be [found here](http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=PbFVZfjTXJQWrnJp&sort_order=popularity&location=London,%20United%20Kingdom&date=Today). I would like this construct a Hash like so:

```
{"Title1" => {:title => 'Title1', :date => 'Date1', :post_code => 'PostCode1'}, 
"Title2" => {:title => 'Title2', :date => 'Date2', :post_code => 'PostCode2'}}
```

When using `events.each('search/events/event/title')`, `events.each('search/events/event/date')`, and `events.each('search/events/event/post_code')`.

So I want to create a Hash from the XML provided by the URL I have included above. Thanks!

Comment: Use `nokogiri`..Its perfect for this..

Comment: I don't know how to [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077206/how-do-i-loop-through-items-in-xml-in-nokogiri-in-ruby) in Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop over the events themselves, not the titles. Something like this

```
events_by_title = {}
elements.each('search/events/event') do |event|
  title = event.get_elements('title').first.text
  events_by_title[title] = {
    :title => title,
    :date => event.get_elements('start_time').first.text
    :post_code => event.get_elements('postal_code').first.text,
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the root element using root() on the REXML:Document object then use each_element("search/events/event") to iterate over "event" node. You can then extract the different values out of it using the different methods on element: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Element.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice the `each_element` method!